# Updating background of single element instead of them all

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make this: if inside of the `.hoca-puan` value is `5,00`, set the element's `background-color: green`. I tried this code but *all* classes turned the green.

```
var deg = $('.hoca-puan').html(); 
if (deg == "5,00") { 
  $('.hoca-puan').css("background-color", "green"); 
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What code? What HTML? What have you tried?

Comment: sorry, my pictures are not added. I shared the code.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We'll need your HTML too.

Comment: Pictures? If you're trying to post pictures, don't post pictures of code, post the actual code instead

Answer (score 3):

It affects all `.hoca-puan` instances because you select them all within the `if` statement.

To evaluate each one individually you need to loop over them, which you can do using `each()`. Then in the handler you can use the `this` keyword to reference only the current element in the iteration:

```js
$('.hoca-puan').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html().trim() == "5,00") {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  }
});
```